# What is the jcifs.smb.client.username property exactly used for?

Tags: java, ntlm, single-sign-on, jcifs

I'm using the JCIFS library to implement Single Sign-On with the NTLMv1 Method. THis is working fine. But now i'm trying to find out, why do i have to specify a username in the configuration of the NTLMHttpFilter in web.xml?

What is this username and password used for?

Comment: Any reason why you use a protocol which was introduced with Windows NT 4 and is considered insecure and outdated for ages? The JCIFS NTLM HTTP Authentication is also not maintaine anymore: http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html And you know that you even need to modify registry settings in Windows Server 2008 R2 to reactivate NTLMv1? You may consider using WAFFLE (http://waffle.codeplex.com/) and NTLMv2 or Kerberos instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm working on a System which is meant to support all of these in terms of backwards compatibility. For example, it already supports waffle for windows servers. So i need JCIFS and Ntlmv1 for really old Systems. (This happens a lot at the customer side). Do you have a link where i can read about reactivating Ntlmv1 through the registry? This would really help me testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the values for *jcifs.smb.client.username* and *jcifs.smb.client.password* are used by jCIFS to log on to the domain controller.